# Unsupported database type sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, liferay, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to set up Liferay with the SQL Server database.
below are configured details.

SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19041: )

Liferay version: liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2

Portal-ext properties file.

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
jdbc.default.username=test
jdbc.default.password=test@123
```

I am getting below error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported database type sqlserver
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it is not programming related, thus off topic on stackoverflow. However, the error message is right: **Unsupported database type sqlserver**. Liferay CE (starting with version 7.0) does not support SQL-Server out of the box. There is a community plugin to provide this compatibility, or you'll have to go with the commercial edition, Liferay DXP. You may also want to start with a more recent release than 7.2.

Comment: Aside... `integratedSecurity=true` or `jdbc.default.username=test; jdbc.default.password=test@123`? Those options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Have you downloaded a [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) for your JRE version and added the appropriate .jar files to your `tomcat/lib/ext` folder? Refer to: [Installing to SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Authentication](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/installing-to-sql-server-using-windows-integrated-authentication)